# Python Rasterio not recognized as a supported file format

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, jpeg-2000

I'm trying to run this python code with anaconda.

I have an error that I can not solve.

I try execute this tutorial : https://towardsdatascience.com/satellite-imagery-access-and-analysis-in-python-jupyter-notebooks-387971ece84b

to work with sentinel-2's image.

At the line:

```
b4 = rio.open(R10+'/T31TFJ_20190905T104029_B04_10m.jp2')
```

I have this error :

```
RasterioIOError: 'image/S2B_MSIL2A_20190905T104029_N0213_R008_T31TFJ_20190905T135151.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T31TFJ_A013047_20190905T104455/IMG_DATA/R10m/T31TFJ_20190905T104029_B04_10m.jp2' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

I remove gdal with command conda remove gdal and re-install with conda install gdal

Any ideas ?

I do every test with GDAL. I Have a error...

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

gdal.UseExceptions()
ds = gdal.Open('test.jp2')

This error : `test.jp2' not recognized as a supported file format.
Drivers gdal problems

other thing, when I installed Gdal with conda, every conflict found. There is already gdal installed on my computer for Qgis (mapping software).